# Using Bigfoot.js with Apache Webserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache

I'm trying to embed [bigfoot.js](http://bigfootjs.com) onto my website. I followed the steps to create an directory in httpdocs called js and copied the bigfoot and jquery files there.

I also added the following JS code to my Header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bigfoot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.bigfoot();
</script>
```

Safaris errorlog tells me that jquery-2.2.3.js and bigfoot.js aren't foung at domain.com/js/file.js. What have I to do, to enable these fileaccess on this path?

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong subdirectory with my index.html...